# Why the PSM results differ using Matching and Matchit in R

Tags: r, match, matching, propensity-score-matching

I conducted prospensity score matching in R using the R-package "Matching" and "Matchit" respectively, but the number of matches were completely different.

The dataset is here [http://web.hku.hk/~bcowling/data/propensity.csv](http://web.hku.hk/%7Ebcowling/data/propensity.csv) or [http://web.hku.hk/~bcowling/examples/propensity.htm](http://web.hku.hk/%7Ebcowling/examples/propensity.htm).
`example <- propensity`

The code using "Matching" was：

`m.ps <- glm(trt ~ age + risk + severity, family="binomial", data=example)`

`example$ps <- predict(m.ps, type="response")`

`PS.m <- Match(Y=example$death, Tr=example$trt, X=example$ps, M=1, caliper=0.2, replace=FALSE)`  
`summary(PS.m )`

```
SE.........  0.041299 
T-stat.....  -2.1126 
p.val......  0.034634 

Original number of observations..............  400 
Original number of treated obs...............  192 
Matched number of observations...............  149 
Matched number of observations  (unweighted).  149 

Caliper (SDs)........................................   0.2 
Number of obs dropped by 'exact' or 'caliper'  43
```

The number of matches was 149.

The code using "MatchIt" was：
`psm<-matchit(trt ~ age+risk+severity, data=example, method="nearest",caliper=0.2)` 
`summary(psm)`

```
Sample Sizes:
         Control Treated
All           208     192
Matched       161     161
Unmatched      47      31
Discarded       0       0
```

The number of matches was 161, and it was different from 149 when using Matching.
Why were they different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two reasons: 1) `Matching` proceeds through the matches in the order of units in the dataset while `MatchIt` by default proceeds through matches based on descending order of the propensity score, and 2) `Matching` uses a nonzero distance tolerance by default, meaning that any two units with a propensity score difference of .00001 or less will be considered exactly matched, whereas `MatchIt` has no such tolerance.

To ensure the results are the same between `Matching` and `MatchIt`, set `m.order = "data"` in `matchit()` and set `distance.tolerance = 0` in `Match()`.

```r
PS.m <- Match(Y=example$death, Tr=example$trt, X=example$ps, M=1, caliper=0.2, replace=FALSE, ties = F,
              distance.tolerance = 0)

psm <- matchit(trt ~ age+risk+severity, data=example, method="nearest",caliper=0.2, 
               m.order = "data")

cobalt::bal.tab(psm, weights = PS.m)
#> Call
#>  matchit(formula = trt ~ age + risk + severity, data = example, 
#>     method = "nearest", m.order = "data", caliper = 0.2)
#> 
#> Balance Measures
#>              Type Diff.matchit Diff.Match
#> distance Distance       0.0043     0.0043
#> age       Contin.       0.0902     0.0902
#> risk      Contin.      -0.0348    -0.0348
#> severity  Contin.      -0.0342    -0.0342
#> 
#> Effective sample sizes
#>         Control Treated
#> All         208     192
#> matchit     149     149
#> Match       149     149
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Here I used `cobalt::bal.tab()` to verify that the result matched sample sizes are the same and the balance statistics match identically, indicating the same matched sample is produced using both methods.

Comment: Thank you so much！I tried to just set "m.order = "data"" in matchit() and it works too. I think it is because "caliper=0.2" in Matching()  cancels the effect of "distance.tolerance = 0". ("distance.tolerance = 0" is included in "caliper=0.2.)

Comment: I got different matches (same number of matches, though) when not specifying `distance.tolerance`, so this is necessary. `distance.tolerance` determines who is matched to whom, which matters for balance in this case. `distance.tolerance` has nothing to do with `caliper`. `caliper` determines who is allowed to be matched with whom; `distance.tolerance` determines who *is* matched to whom among those allowed.

Comment: It makes sense. I also found that although they have the same number of matches, mabybe the matches are still a little different. Because they have the different mean of the variable in the control group after matched. (For example, of the control group after matched, the mean age is 56.1477 using `Matching() set.seed(100)` , but it is 56.0403 using `matchIt()`. Maybe it is because `Matching` also proceeds through random order of units?

Comment: If two control units are equidistant from a treated unit, one will be selected at random. A high `distance.tolerance` makes more control units equidistant from each treated unit. Even with `distance.tolerance = 0`, it is still possible for two controls to be equidistant if they have the same propensity score. Adding a small amount of random noise to the propensity score (e.g., `example$ps + rnorm(400, 0, .001)`) prevents this.